# Readin excel file in java?

Tags: java, excel

I need to read a column from a xls file, but **1 cell per hour**. I am using the jxl library. I tried using a timer but it reads all the cells at once from hour to hour.

This is how i get the first cell of my column: (sheet.getCell(0,4)), where 0 is the column and 4 is the first cell.

How can i get all the cells from 4 to 10 but with 1 cell per hour ?

Example code:

```
 timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
   Cell b3;
   double numberb3=0;
   int i;
   @Override
   public void run() {
   Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheet(0);

   b3 = sheet.getCell(0, 4);

   if(b3.getType()==CellType.NUMBER){
         NumberCell nc = (NumberCell) b3;
         numberb3= nc.getValue();
     }
    System.out.println("="+numberb3);

  }
}, 2*60*1000,60*60*1000);
```

Comment: Another possibility is to improve your code to make it serve your task correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what librarys are out there, but generally there are 2 options:

1. Access the file via the COM-Interface Excel provides
2. Read the Excel-File (btw: basically .xlsx is a zip-file) manually

Consider that for 1. Excel has to be installed on the Computer your program will be running.